# Make font size of numerator the same as denominator?

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, amsmath, fontsize

I have a simple question, I would like to make the font-size of the numerator the same as that of my denominator. For example, something like this:

```
e^{-j \frac{2 \pi n k}{K_F}}
```

gives me an ugly looking equation..., where the $K_F$ looks way bigger than the stuff on the top.

Is there a way to make the top and bottom look 'nicer' together?

Thanks.

Comment: I would prefer `2\pi n k/K_F`.

Comment: The size is the same, but the denominator has capital letters, which are bigger.

Comment: For such large superscripts it is recommended to use `\exp` instead: `$\exp (-j \frac{2 \pi n k}{K_F} ) $` or
`$\exp (-2 \pi n j k /K_F ) $`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Hmm, I suppose those can work, but I would really like to use the $e$ and not exp. Is there a way to simply make the denom smaller?

Comment: You could use a scaling factor (but I will not recommend this): `$ e^{-j \frac{2 \pi n k}{\smash{\scalebox{.5}{$K_{F}$}}}} $` (requires to load `graphicx`).

Comment: I you make the uppercase `K` smaller, it would look quite similar to the lowercase `k` and would confuse the reader. Clarity is quite important in math.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtain something that more or less looks like what you want.

First method: in the denominator you pass in text mode, choose a smaller font size and return to math mode. I give two examples, with `\small` and `footnotesize`.

Second method: you use a font that has slanted small caps, like Latin Modern or MinonPro. You declare a new math alphabet to use them in math mode. I give an example with the `cfr-lm` package, where slanted smallcaps are called `sishape`.

```
    \documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

    \usepackage{cfr-lm}
    \usepackage{mathtools, nccmath, textcomp, relsize}

    \DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsi}{T1}{clm}{m}{si}

    \begin{document}

    \[ e^{-j \frac{2 π n k}{K_{\!F}}} \]%

    \[ e^{-j \frac{2 π n k}{\text{\small$ \scriptscriptstyle K_{\!F}$}}} \]%

    \[ e^{-j \frac{2 π n k}{\text{\footnotesize$ \scriptscriptstyle K_{\!F }$}}} \]%

    \[ e^{-j \frac{2 π n k}{\mathsi{k_f}}} \]%

    \end{document}
```

[image: Result:]

Comment: Sorry: I don't understand what's happening. I loaded a .png of the result and it doesn't display.

Comment: Look at your browser tab it's not loading the page. Imgur is down